# What clustering method would give the maximal Silhouette score?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I know that you can calculate Silhouette scores for the output of different types of clustering algorithms.

My question here is different, namely: is there any clustering algorithm that is designed/known/prone to produce the maximal mean silhouette score?

See some example `R` code below.
It contains a brute-force solution of a clustering problem, where I calculate the [Silhouette score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silhouette_(clustering)) for each cluster in cluster `cli` a bit differently, namely:

a(cli) = mean(max(d(i,j))), for i,j in the same cluster

i.e. I find the maximal *intra*-cluster pairwise distance of each object i in `cli`, and take their mean.

b(cli) = mean(min(d(i,j))), for i,j in different clusters

i.e. I find the minimal *inter*-cluster pairwise distance of each object i in `cli` and take their mean.

s(cli) = (b-a)/max(a,b)

Then the overall silhouette score of a specific clustering is the mean of s(cli) over all `cli`'s.

I do this because I need to make clusters that have as few objects as possible with small distance to objects in other clusters, and as few objects as possible with large distance to objects in the same cluster.

```
# 1. User parameters

# Number of objects to simulate
N = 20
# Proportions of clusters to make (the length determines how many clusters to make)
cluster_proportions = c(1,1)

# 2. Simulate the coordinates of the N objects in 2D and calculate their distance matrix

set.seed(328409)
coords <- matrix(data = runif(2*N, -5, 5), ncol = 2)
dm <- as.matrix(dist(coords))
#dm[diag(dm)] <- NA

# 3. Evaluate all brute force solutions

sizes = ceiling(N * cluster_proportions / sum(cluster_proportions))
sizes[which.max(sizes)] <- sizes[which.max(sizes)] + N - sum(sizes)
ncls <- length(sizes)

require(arrangements)
nperms <- npermutations(x = 1:ncls, freq = sizes)
iperm <- ipermutations(x = 1:ncls, freq = sizes)

highest_mean_silhouette_score <- -1
best_clustering <- NULL

for (i in 1:nperms) {
  
  cl <- iperm$getnext()
  
  # For each possible clustering cl, compute a 'psedudo-silhouette' score for each cluster; find the clustering for which the mean score is maximal
  
  current_mean_silhouette_score <- mean(sapply(1:ncls, function(cli) {
    
    if (sum(cl == cli) == 1) {
      s <- 0
    } else {
    mindists_current_cl_to_other_cls <- apply(dm[cl != cli, cl == cli], 1, min)
    maxdists_current_cl_to_current_cl <- apply(dm[cl == cli, cl == cli], 1, max)
    b <- mean(mindists_current_cl_to_other_cls)
    a <- mean(maxdists_current_cl_to_current_cl)
    s <- (b - a) / max(a,b)
    }
    s
  }))
  
  if (current_mean_silhouette_score > highest_mean_silhouette_score) {
    highest_mean_silhouette_score <- current_mean_silhouette_score
    best_clustering <- cl
    cat("\nCurrent highest mean score = ", highest_mean_silhouette_score)
    cat("\nCurrent best clustering = ", best_clustering)
    plot(coords, pch = 16, col = best_clustering, main = paste0("Current highest mean score = ", highest_mean_silhouette_score), asp = 1)
  }
  
  #cat("\ni = ",i,", current_score = ", current_score, ", clustering = ",cl)
  
}
```

Here is the final result I get for this simulation:

[image]

Obviously I could not run the brute-force solver in a real situation (even just calculating the distance matrix could be challenging, with the numbers I am dealing with).

Hence my question: **what clustering algorithm do you think should be used to get a result as close as possible to the one obtained by the above?** (meaning of course in general, not only for this specific example or simulation).

Thanks!

**EDIT** after further work

Tried out R's `hclust` (see R script below).
Looks like `method = "complete"` gives me a high silhouette score, better than `"median"` or `"average"`, and the result for 2 clusters is the same as the brute force one, at least for this example.

Shame that hierarchical clustering is also limited to relatively small sets... **does anyone know of faster / less memory-hungry substitutes for `hclust`?**

```
# 1. User parameters

# Number of objects to simulate
N = 20

# 2. Simulate the coordinates of the N objects in 2D and calculate their distance matrix

set.seed(328409)
coords <- matrix(data = runif(2*N, -5, 5), ncol = 2)
dm <- dist(coords)

# 3. Try hierarchical clustering

hc <- hclust(dm, method = "complete")
dm <- as.matrix(dm)

highest_mean_silhouette_score <- -1
best_clustering <- NULL

for (ncls in 2:N) {
  
  cl <- cutree(hc, k = ncls)
  
  # For each possible clustering cl, compute a 'psedudo-silhouette' score for each cluster; find the clustering for which the mean score is maximal
  
  current_mean_silhouette_score <- mean(sapply(1:ncls, function(cli) {
    
    if (sum(cl == cli) == 1) {
      s <- 0
    } else {
      mindists_current_cl_to_other_cls <- apply(dm[cl != cli, cl == cli], 1, min)
      maxdists_current_cl_to_current_cl <- apply(dm[cl == cli, cl == cli], 1, max)
      b <- mean(mindists_current_cl_to_other_cls)
      a <- mean(maxdists_current_cl_to_current_cl)
      s <- (b - a) / max(a,b)
    }
    s
  }))
  
  if (current_mean_silhouette_score > highest_mean_silhouette_score) {
    highest_mean_silhouette_score <- current_mean_silhouette_score
    best_clustering <- cl
    cat("\nCurrent highest mean score = ", highest_mean_silhouette_score)
    cat("\nCurrent best clustering = ", best_clustering)
    plot(coords, pch = 16, col = best_clustering, main = paste0("N = ",N,", # clusters = ",ncls,", current highest mean score = ", round(highest_mean_silhouette_score,3)), asp = 1)
  }
  
}
```

Comment: I see someone is voting to close this question because it belongs to cross validated rather than stackoverflow. I posted it here because I saw a lot of posts about clustering in SO, but I have no problem moving it if considered appropriate. Just let me know so I don't waste your time or mine posting here.